# Delphi WSDL tag property as attribute

Tags: xml, delphi, wsdl

Here's an example of a SOAP response :

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <MethodResponse>
            <return>
                <tag1>1</tag1>
                <tag2>2</tag2>
            </return>
            <return>
                <tag1>3</tag1>
                <tag2>4</tag2>
            </return>
        </MethodResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

When the WSDL is imported Delphi generates a class to represent each tag return like this:

```
class returnObj = (TRemotable)
    tag1: integer;
    tag2: integer;
property
    // etc
end;
```

Now a tag3 was added, and instead of adding it alongside tag2 and tag1 is was put as an attribute of return, like this:

```
<return tag3="description">
```

Is there a way for Delphi to map this tag3?

And what if another one is added in tag2? like this:

```
<tag2 tag4="another description">
```